# how to check if all field are filled in with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

how can I add conditions to rails validations. For example, check if all field are filled in before proceeding to other validations.

Comment: are you asking about making a custom validation in the model, or do you want to validate the form before allowing the user to submit it?

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord provides a callback option called [`before_validation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) which will allow a method to run before validations.

In your model, add

```
class XModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  before_validation :check_for_existence
  ...

  private

    def check_for_existence
      self.attributes.each do |attr|
        return false if self[attr].nil?
      end
    end
end
```

So basically, `check_for_existence` method is called before all other validations. `check_for_existence` method goes through all the object's attributes and inspects the values for each attribute. If any of them are `nil`, the method will return `false` and all the later callbacks are cancelled including validations.

Comment: You know like the way large site like facebook or twitter do it.

Comment: Francis, you should consider rewriting your question in a descriptive manner so that responders can help with your needs better.

Comment: `self.attributes.each do |attr|` needs a value beside of the key... because it will then just take the array with key and value and `self[Array]` doesnt make sense